# Link Login System in Flutter app to Supabase database

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase

I am trying to create a flutter app and one of my goals is to setup a login system with a cloud-based database. The database i am trying to use is [Supabase](https://supabase.com). The way i want to set this up (for now) is that i want to manually write data into my database table and if the login forms data matches it redirects the user to the home page of the app. However i keep getting this error

Here is my pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
flutter:
  sdk: flutter
supabase: ^1.11.11
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

```
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'supabase' in 'package:supabase/supabase.dart'.
lib/main.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'package:supabase/supabase.dart'
import 'package:supabase/supabase.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:8:3: Error: Undefined name 'Supabase'.
  Supabase.initialize(
  ^^^^^^^^
```

Here is /the code i have tried

```
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:supabase/supabase.dart';

import 'login_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
  Supabase.initialize(
    url: '',
    anonKey: '',
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Flutter App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: /LVisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
// login_page.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: LoginForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _usernameController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _login() {
    if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
      String? username = _usernameController.text;
      String? password = _passwordController.text;

      // Implement your login logic here

      // For now, let's just print the username and password
      print('Username: $username');
      print('Password: $password');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: _usernameController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Username',
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value?.isEmpty ?? true) {
                return 'Please enter your username';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _passwordController,
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Password',
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value?.isEmpty ?? true) {
                return 'Please enter your password';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _login,
            child: Text('Login'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
// home_page.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Welcome to the Home Page!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Supabase in your **Flutter** project, I'd advise you to follow their documentation: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/installing

It's apparant that you're trying to use classes from the `supabase_flutter` package whilst having imported the dart-only version `supabase`, which runs on a `SupabaseClient`, unlike the initialization method in your code sample.

*Edit*: If I was not being clear enough, you need to change your `supabase` dependency to `supabase_flutter`.

Comment: Thanks! i appreciate it. I got that to work now i am doing almost the exact same thing but with firebase firestore because i want to see which one is better on free plan.